# show collections on Mongo shell returns nothing but it works on Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, shell, pymongo

I have a Mongo DB and I'm trying to access to it though mongo shell.

```
mongosh --host 192.168.1.25 --port 27017 -u user -p pass
```

I can log in with no problems and I can see the databases on the server but when I try seeing the collections I receive empty arrays.

```
test > show databases
<Databases listed correctly>
test > use rightdatabase
rightdatabase > show collections

rightdatabase > db.getCollectionNames()
[]
```

The output of db.stats also suggest the databases are empty (every parameter of the response is 0). However, if I log in through PyMongo like this, I get a proper result:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
try:
    conn = MongoClient('192.168.1.25', 27017, username='user', password='pass')
    print('Conected successfully!')
except:
    print('Could not conect to MongoDB')
db = conn['rightdatabase']
db.command("dbstats")
```

That cell returns the following data:

```
#Output
{'db': '######',
 'collections': 16,
 'views': 0,
 'objects': 52283952,
 'avgObjSize': 1349.6649228237375,
 'dataSize': 70565816041.0,
 'storageSize': 23785156608.0,
 ...}
```

I've read comments saying that it could be a matter of versions. I'm using Mongo shell alone  in Windows (not the one included in a Mongo Server installation), version 1.10.1, but I've done this before in the same computer with no issues.

Comment: Are you missing a line or two of code in that Python sniper? What is `db`? By default you'll be in the `test` database when you log in with the shell. You can `use <DBNAME>` to change it after connected. If `test` is empty and your Python code is using a different database then that would explain the discrepancy that you are observing

Comment: @user20042973 I've added some clarifications. I switch properly to the right database before trying to use `show collections`.

Comment: The might be an authentication thing.  Try running `db.runCommand("connectionStatus")` to see if it lists the user and roles you think you should have

Comment: @Joe I've checked and I'm effectively logged as a root (admin).